# nginx conditional Accept header

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, http-headers

Some mobile devices send the following incorrect requests to our servers :

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Accept:
User-Agent : xxx
```

The empty Accept header causes our Ruby on Rails server to throw back a 500 error.

In Apache, the following directive allows us to rewrite the header before sending it to the application RoR server in order to cope with the broken devices :

```
    RequestHeader edit Accept ^$ "*/*" early
```

We're currently setting up nginx, but achieving the same work-around is proving difficult. We are able to set :

```
  proxy_set_header Accept */*;
```

However, this seems to have to be done inconditionally. Whenever trying to do :

```
if ($http_accept !~ ".") {
  proxy_set_header Accept */*;
}
```

It complains with the message :

```
"proxy_set_header" directive is not allowed here
```

So, using nginx, how can we set the HTTP Accept header to `*/*` when it is empty before sending the request to the application server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
set $acceptHeader $http_accept;
if ($acceptHeader !~ ".") {
  set $acceptHeader '/';
}
proxy_set_header Accept $acceptHeader;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
map $http_accept $accept_header {
    default $http_accept;
    ""      */*;    
}

server {

    ...

    proxy_set_header Accept $accept_header;
}
```

- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
- http://nginx.org/r/map